# Opening embedded Excel file crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file embedded in a workbook, as I need all users to have access to it, which may not happen if it's on a network. I have this code to extract it from Excel to the users' temp drive.

When I step through the code it runs fine but crashes on execution.

```
Private Function DownloadOutlookFile()
    Dim oEmbFile As Object
    Dim x As String: x = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SO_File.Name).OLEObjects(1)
    oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
    Workbooks("Worksheet in " & x).SaveAs FileName:="C:\Temp\Supression.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Workbooks("Worksheet in " & x).Close
End Function
```

EDIT: Removed sleep code as it isn't helping and was only testing.

Comment: Joel, if you want wait time, instead of Sleep, try `Application.Wait Now+TimeValue("00:00:02")` (two seconds just an example). Also, perhaps using `Application.ScreenUpdating  = False` then `True` - before & after your `SaveAs` method, respectively. Let me know! Danny.

Comment: The Sleep was just part of my code to see if putting in breaks would help the code run which didn't help. Screen updating didn't help either thanks, I hadn't tried that yet as its part of the upstream process.

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  What is the error message.  You need to help us, so that we can help you.

Comment: There isn't an error, Excel just crashes. From what I can see it is crashing on the saveas part as it manages to open the file.